# Numba nested functions with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numba

I have this nested function:

```
@jit
def offset_period_generator(offset, period, forward=False):
    def offset_period(curr_datetime):
        if not forward: return (curr_datetime - (pd.Timedelta(offset) + pd.Timedelta(period)),
                                curr_datetime - pd.Timedelta(offset))
        return (curr_datetime + pd.Timedelta(offset) - pd.Timedelta(period),
                curr_datetime + pd.Timedelta(offset))
    return offset_period
```

Its throwing the following error: Numba encountered the use of a language feature it does not support in this context:  (op code: make_function not supported). If the feature is explicitly supported it is likely that the result of the expression is being used in an unsupported manner.

I read the documentation and Numba is supposed to be supporting nested python functions.

I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, you cannot currently return an inner function:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html#inner-function-and-closure

Additionally Numba cannot do any compilation on pandas objects so you really aren't going to see any benefit of decorating this function with `numba.jit`.

Comment: I was not thinking about performance benefits, I was thinking about GPU processing, because pandas doesn't support it. :(

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "I was thinking about GPU processing..."?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html , in the Numba section it mentions that numba supports gpu compilation.

Comment: The example in the pandas docs only gets a speed improvement because it is passing in `df['a'].values`, where `.values` exposes the raw underlying numpy array that numba can understand. Pandas specific things are not supported (like pandas time deltas).

Comment: Okey! Thank you :)

Comment: would cython maybe return inner functions?

Comment: Cython should support the entirety of the python language with few exceptions, so I think it would work. My best advice would be to give it a try.